# Running TCP server in Java Spring/Springboot framework instead of http/https

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sockets, tcp

I want to write a TCP/IP Socket based application using Java Spring/Spring Boot framework. However I am facing problem in bringing the TCP server up. Whenever I init the application it brings the tomcat up instead of my tcp server port. My requirement is that the my application will act as a TCP server/client based on the configuration and will connect/accept connection from Third Party. It shall process the requests and send responses back. The application needs to receive/send stream of bytes.

I tried googling a lot and found a few articles indicating implementing a CommandLineRunner interface of SpringBoot however that also did not work. Could you please assist on this

Comment: Spring Boot works with embedded Tomcat. You could of course go and turn of that embedded Tomcat and stuff but that would get more complicated where you task is to write a simple server probably a university assignment. So if I was you I would definitely not use spring boot, implement the server yourself based on any of million "your own tcp server in java" tutorial and then add spring (not boot) as dependency container if you wish.

Comment: @JAsgarov: Thank you for the response. Yes, I need the spring as a dependency container only where this server module has a dependency on the provider module (another spring based) which communicate with DB for CRUD operations and couple of more microservices with whom this module communicate via Kafka. However this module is not a assignment rather a problem in hand where it will communicate with Payment Schemes over TCP/IP and internal microservices using KAFKA Bus. Thank you

Comment: if it is real work/life situation what is the problem with embedded Tomcat? It also uses TCP so..

Comment: I want to run a TCP Socket based server (socket programming) with more control on the sockfds etc. than running/using embedded tomcat/jetty and yet need the autoconfiguration from boot